# orderBy best selling product

Tags: mysql, sql, database, laravel, eloquent

so I have 2 tables, products and sales.

Product is ABC, and in the sales A = 16, B= 18, C=10.

and I want to show the products ordered by best selling so the order would be like BAC, how to do that?

thank you for your help :)

---

Sorry guys if I wasnt clear enough,so here is my complete scenario

**Products table**

```
milk
egg
chocolate
```

**Sales table**

```
milk
milk
egg
milk
chocolate
egg
chocolate
chocolate
milk
```

and then in the homepage I wanna show products order by best selling, so the order would be

```
milk
chocolate
egg
```

I still dont have any query as I still confused how to do that

Comment: please add your product and sales table schema and model

Comment: Use Join between Product and Sales and at the end do order by sales.count desc or directly do group by on sales table and order by count

Comment: in your join query try this "orderBy('something', 'asc')"

Comment: Surely you must have tried a query.  Can you include it?

Comment: share your complete laravel query ?

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the tables schema but if it is a *belongsTo* relationship

```
class Product extends Model
{
   public function sale()
   {
      return $this->belongsTo(App\Models\Sale::class,'sale_id')
   }
}
```

Then

```
$products = Product::with('sale')->orderBy('sale.count')->get();
```